# how to get access and refresh tokens with OAuth2?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth, request, oauth-2.0

I am using VB.NET to get access with OAuth2.
making request for offline access,
looks similar:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
>   scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&
>   state=%2Fprofile&
>   redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Fcode&
>   response_type=code& client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com&
>   access_type=offline

I am struggeling for many hours.How can I get Refresh Token?
I know that I should make request to get `grant_type` which contains a value of Authorization code and so I will have Access and Refresh Tokens but how can I solve it programmatically?

Comment: That link doesn't work, but it's academic. What have you already tried? You'll need to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to request access and receive authorization.

Comment: i'm so far that i have authorization url given above. i'm using service accounts ( that means authorization without user action), and at the moment i want to get Access and Refresh Tokens. how to do it with HttpWebRequest and Response?? can you give some code example please??